# Jquery-validation filesize show a human readable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to show 1MB error message instead 1024 in this script:

http://jsfiddle.net/tyaenm09/37/

Using jquery-validation plugin with filesize extension.
I can force message `MAX FILE SIZE {0}` to `MAX FILE SIZE 1MB` of course, but if i need to implement a second input file in the same page with a different filesize allowed, the message need to be variable.

Comment: Code should be included *in the question itself* instead of linked to a 3rd party source. Also show `jquery-validation plugin with filesize extension` code you want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do 2 things here.

- Pass the appropriate number of *bytes* as the max size
- Use a humanize library to turn the size into something more readable. [filesizejs](https://github.com/avoidwork/filesize.js) seems to be a good choice.

```js
var maxBytes = 1024000;
console.log(filesize(maxBytes,{exponent:2,round:1}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/filesize/3.5.11/filesize.min.js"></script>
```

Then, you could just pass the appropriate max size (again, in bytes) with each file upload field

```js
$(function(){
  $.validator.addMethod('filesize', function (value, element, param) {
      return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)
  }, function(size){
    return "MAX SIZE " + filesize(size,{exponent:2,round:1});
  });

  $('#form').validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                minlength: 6,
                required: true
            },

            file1: {
                required: true,
                filesize: 1000 * 1024,   
            },
            file2: {
                required: true,
                filesize: 1000 * 512,   
            }
        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        errorElement: 'div',
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/filesize/3.5.11/filesize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
  <div>
    <label>File1 (max 1Mb)</label>
    <input name="file1" type="file" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>File2 (max 0.5Mb)</label>
    <input name="file2" type="file"  />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Very nice solution! Thanks